# How to display Devise account details on a profile page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Using Devise I would like to display User account information such as profile name, first & last name etc on another page called profile page within my rails application.

I have created a controller called profiles with a view called profile/show
In the controller have added the below code

```
def show
    @user = User.find_by_profile_name(params[:id])
    if @user
      render action: :show
    else
      render file: 'public/404', status: 404, formats: [:html]
        end
    end
end
```

In the view profiles/show I have the following code

```
<%= @user.profile_name %>
```

and the route is get 'profiles/show'.

My issue is when I do all of the above the profile name of the user still does not display on the profile page? There are no errors that come up it just doesn't display. I am not sure what code I am missing. I have checked the console and the user does have a profile name save to that ID and this is also in the devise account settings. So I am not sure how to get this information to display?

Comment: You sure are passing profile_name in the params[:id] ?

Answer (score 1):

In Rails you would usually set it up like follow to take leverage of convention over configuration:

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :users, only: [:show, :index]
```

---

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # ...

  def self.find_by_uid!(uid)
    User.find_by!("profile_name = :p OR id = :p", p: uid)
  end

end
```

---

```
# app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController
  # GET /users/:id
  def show
    @user = User.find_by_uid!(params[:id])
    # Rails does the magic.
  end

  # GET /users
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end
end
```

---

```
<%- # app/views/users/show.html.erb -%>
<h1><%= @user.profile_name %></h1>
```

The only special part here is that in the user model we create a class method which will query by `id` or `profile_name`. The reason that this is important is that it lets you use `link_to(@user)` and `redirect_to(@user)` as expected.

Which is also why we use `resources :users`. When the route name and the model line up the Rails polymorphic route handlers are able to do their job. If you want to use `/profiles` thats fine but never `/profiles/show` - including the action in the route defeats the whole purpose of REST.

The show action will render `users/show.html.erb` by default.  So you rarely need to explicitly render in your controller.

```
render action: :foo
```

is only used when you want to render a template with the same name as another action, its usually used as follows:

```
def create
  @something = Something.new
  if @something.save
    redirect_to(@something)
  else
    render action: :new # renders views/something/new.html.erb
  end
end
```

If you want to explicitly render a template you would do `render :foo` or `render "foo/bar"`.

And when you use `find` or `find_by!` it will raise an exception if the record is not found which by default will render the static 404 template. Reproducing this error handling in your actions is not very desirable since it violates the DRY pinciple.

Comment: If the user name still does not show try using `<%= debug @user %>` in the view. If its not showing up you need to configure the devise params sanitizer.

Comment: Thanks really appreciate the detailed reply :)